# [gmapping] get current robot-position?

Tags: navigation, gmapping, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks!

Rosaria provides me with odometry, which is then given to gmapping and (along with some laser-sensordata) processed. As the robot moves in the world this creates a map of its environment.
Now I wish to get the current position of my robot but can't quite figure out how. My understanding is as follows:

I need

- a TransformListener from gmapping to be able to transform odometry into world-coordinates.
- a Subscriber to get the odometry in the first place.

Since both need to be handled with callbacks I need to use gobal variables to get information from one to the other. This in turn makes it necessary to think about synchronization and race-conditions.

Is this really the proper way to do it / do I have an error in my understanding? If so, how do i go about solving the race-condition problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10315/%5Bgmapping%5D-get-current-robot-position?/) by [G_Threepwood](https://answers.ros.org/users/710/g_threepwood/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-06-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You just need one TransformListener and listen for the /map -> /base_link transform.

The transform listener will take the gmapping and odometry transforms and build the correct one from that automatically.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-12-19**:
@dornhege how can i acomplish to make this tranfsormlistener?? Can you give some details? Because ive been unable to mak eit work, thanks

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-12-20**:
Check these: http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials